# Angular - Initial checked values for material checked list

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to get initial checked value into mat-tree component as it is described in following StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-checklist-1cqqha

I will have only two levels of nodes. Thus I have tried to toggle node if it is checked in following manner:

```
  update(value){
    this.treeData = value;
    this.dataSource.data = this.treeData;

    for(let itemG of this.treeData) {
      for(let item of itemG.value) {
        if(item.checked) {
          this.checklistSelection.toggle(item);
          this.checklistSelection.select(item);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However that did not helped.
Could anyone help me here?

Much appreciations!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After digging and debuggin I have figured out that working code is:

```
  update(value){
    this.treeData = value;
    this.dataSource.data = this.treeData;

    for(let itemG of this.treeData) {
      for(let item of itemG.children.value) {
        if(item.checked) {
          this.checklistSelection.toggle(item);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and everything is working as expected :)

Can anyone suggest better solution?

Comment: could you please post a working/updated stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You should already have dataChange subscription in ngOnInit.
Add checkAll method (and call after dataSource.data gets changed) and that should mark all items as selected.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  
  ... // removed the rest of the code for brevity
  
  this._database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      this.checkAll();  // this is added
    });
}

checkAll(): void {
    for(let item of this.treeControl.dataNodes) {
      this.checklistSelection.select(item);
    }
  }
```